# How to add hexagon mosaic to a photo?

Tags: image-processing

I want to put a hexagon mosaic on the area of the picture (the effect is similar to the figure below):

[image]

```
ImageCompose[ img, 
 ImageTransformation[img, 18 Floor[#/18] + 1 &, DataRange -> Full, 
  Masking -> Rectangle[{50, 50}, {150, 150}], Padding -> Transparent]]
```

[image]

But the above code can only generate square mesh mosaic in the specified area. What can I do to make a hexagon mosaic?

**Image used in Code:**

[image]

Comment: The effect is reminiscent of some of the answers to the question [Artistic image vectorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8507/731).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to find a function that converts a pixel coordinate into a hexagon center, and recolor  the image that way (i.e. similar to your `ImageTransformation` approach). However, when looking into it, it seemed like it could take a while to get it right. I decided to look for a solution that would be easier to implement and easier to understand, and I came up with the following.

We start by defining a function that takes an offset $(x, y)$ and a width and height, and converts that into a collection of polygons:

```
polygon[r_, c_, s_] := Module[{xOff, yOff},
  If[
   OddQ[c],
   yOff = 2 Cos[30 Degree] r + Cos[30 Degree],
   yOff = 2 Cos[30 Degree] r
   ];
  xOff = (1 + Sin[30 Degree]) c;
  Polygon[s (# + {xOff, yOff}) & /@ CirclePoints[6]]
  ]

hexagonalLattice[{width_, height_}, {xOff_, yOff_}, scale_] := Module[{nx, ny},
  nx = Ceiling[width/(scale (1 + Sin[30 Degree]))];
  ny = Ceiling[height/((2 scale + 1) Cos[30 Degree])];
  Flatten@Table[Normal@Translate[polygon[r, c, scale], {xOff, yOff}], {r, 0, ny}, {c, 0, nx}]
  ]

Graphics[{
  FaceForm[White],
  EdgeForm[Black],
  hexagonalLattice[{150, 150}, {50, 50}, 4]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I attempt to convert `Translate[Polygon[...]]` into `Polygon` using `Normal`. This works for 3D primitives but, for unknown reasons, it does not yet work for 2D primitives. I therefore patch `Normal` to do this:

```
Unprotect[Normal];
Normal@Translate[Polygon[coords_], {xOff_, yOff_}] := Polygon[# + {xOff, yOff} & /@ coords]
Protect[Normal];
```

We now create a collection of polygons corresponding to the region that we want to mask, get the centroids of the polygons, and get the corresponding colors from the image. We can then use `HighlightImage` to draw the polygons with the correct color into the image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JveCc.jpg"];
lattice = hexagonalLattice[{100, 100}, {50, 50}, 8];
centroids = RegionCentroid /@ lattice;
colors = PixelValue[img, centroids];
primitives = Transpose[{
    Directive[
       EdgeForm[None],
       Opacity[1],
       RGBColor[#]
       ] & /@ colors,
    lattice
    }];

HighlightImage[img, primitives]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the same with a more detailed lattice so that it is easier to see that the color assignment works:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) Curently the polygons overlap. To avoid this, add `EdgeForm[None]` like `Transpose[{Directive[{RGBColor@#, EdgeForm[None]}] & /@ colors, lattice}]` instead of `Transpose[{RGBColor /@ colors, lattice}]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried your edited code? It works as before the edit...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I honestly didn't think I needed to - it seemed quite obvious how it should work, considering how `Opacity` worked in that version of my code. Well, updated it again now.